# Anyone know all Method Name of DirectoryEntry.Invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, adsi

Anyone know all Method Name of DirectoryEntry.Invoke

Comment: You mean to list all methods of Active Directory Domain Services ?

Comment: That is what I think the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

User related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsuser

Group related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsgroup

Some others:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iads

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadscontainer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsnamespaces

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsopendsobject

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/

(taken from: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21282035/DirectoryEntry-Invoke-Methods.html)

Comment: all the link is dead....

Comment: Dont know about any document, But you can use,
`
DirectoryEntry dirEntry

ArrayList props = new ArrayList();
foreach (string strAttrName in dirEntry.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
 props.Add(strAttrName);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the methods for the [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772305%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The Invoke calls call the ADSI methods (atleast that is my understanding)

Comment: The first two links are broken. To you know where they are now?

Comment: Dont know about any document, But you can use,
`
DirectoryEntry dirEntry

ArrayList props = new ArrayList();
foreach (string strAttrName in dirEntry.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
 props.Add(strAttrName);
}
`

Comment: Just read c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\xxxxxxxxxxx\um\Iads.h